# Lua string.find() error

Tags: lua

So I'm writing a Lua script and I tested it but I got an error that I don't know how to fix:

`.\search.lua:10: malformed pattern (missing ']')`

Below is my code. If you know what I did wrong, it would be very helpful if you could tell me.

```
weird = "--[[".."\n"
function readAll(file)
    local c = io.open(file, "rb")
    local j = c:read("*all")
    c:close()
    return(j)
end
function blockActive()
    local fc = readAll("functions.lua")
    if string.find(fc,weird) ~= nil then
        require("blockDeactivated")
        return("false")
    else
        return("true")
    end
end
print(blockActive())
```

Edit: first comment had the answer. I changed
`weird = "--[[".."\n"` to `weird = "%-%-%[%[".."\r"` The `\n` to `\r` change was because it was actually supposed to be that way in the first place.

Comment: Solution #1: `string.find(fc,weird,1,true)`, Solution #2: `weird = "%-%-%[%[".."\n"`

Comment: Yep, that worked for me. I had to change the "\n" to "\r" but that was because I started off with the wrong thing in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This errors because `string.find` uses [Lua Patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).

Most non-alpha-numeric characters, such as `"[", ".", "-"` etc. convey special meaning.

`string.find(fc,weird)`, or better, `fc:find(weird)` is trying to parse these special characters, and erroring.

You can use these patterns to cancel out your other patterns, however.

```lua
weird = ("--[["):gsub("%W","%%%0") .. "\r?\n"
```

This is a little daunting, but it will hopefully make sense.

the `("--[[")` is the orignal first part of your weird string, working as expected.

`:gsub()` is a function that replaces a pattern with another one. Once again, see [Patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).

`"%W"` is a pattern that matches every string that isn't a letter, a number, or an underscore.

`%%%0` replaces everything that matches with itself (`%0` is a string that represents everything in this match), following a `%`, which is escaped.

So this means that `[[` will be turned into `%[%[`, which is how find, and similar patterns 'escape' special characters.

The reason `\n` is now `\r?\n` refers back to these patterns. This matches it if it ends with a `\n`, like it did before. However, if this is running on windows, a newline might look like `\r\n`. (You can read up on this [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)). A `?` following a character, `\r` in this case, means it can *optionally* match it. So this matches both `--[[\n` *and* `--[[\r\n`, supporting both windows and linux.

Now, when you run your `fc:find(weird)`, it's running `fc:find("%-%-%[%[\r?\n")`, which should be exactly what you want.

Hope this has helped!

*Finished code if you're a bit lazy*

```lua
weird = ("--[["):gsub("%W","%%%0") .. "\r?\n" // Escape "--[[", add a newline. Used in our find.

// readAll(file)
// Takes a string as input representing a filename, returns the entire contents as a string.
function readAll(file)
    local c = io.open(file, "rb")   // Open the file specified by the argument. Read-only, binary (Doesn't autoformat things like \r\n)
    local j = c:read("*all")        // Dump the contents of the file into a string.
    c:close()                       // Close the file, free up memory.
    return j                        // Return the contents of the string.
end

// blockActive()
// returns whether or not the weird string was matched in 'functions.lua', executes 'blockDeactivated.lua' if it wasn't.
function blockActive()
    local fc = readAll("functions.lua") // Dump the contents of 'functions.lua' into a string.
    if fc:find(weird) then              // If it functions.lua has the block-er.
        require("blockDeactivated")     // Require (Thus, execute, consider loadfile instead) 'blockDeactived.lua'
        return false                    // Return false.
    else
        return true                     // Return true.
    end
end
print(blockActive()) // Test? the blockActve code.
```

Comment: Check the comments of my question. Thanks, but I found the answer more than a week ago.

Comment: _Oh_. Well, enjoy my little fact filled write-up.

Comment: lol, it was actually really helpful go some other things as well. I actually didn't know about how Windows formats new lines as `\r\n` and that had helped me with several new scripts I have written. So thanks.

Comment: @TheElementalofCreation If you really want, removing the `b` from your `"rb"` will read the file as text instead of bytes, which converts all `\r\n`s into just `\n`.

Comment: very true, however this is part of a much larger code, and the readAll() function is used a lot in it to read files that it must use "rb" for